# Python: the variable not mentioned in the code is overwritten. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have two list of pandas dataframes, and when I rewrite the second list, I am wondering why the first dataframe is also overwritten. I want to update the second, but not the first. How should I do it?

```
df_list_temp1[0]
Out[153]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6

df_list_temp1[1]
Out[154]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6

df_list_temp2 = df_list_temp1

df_list_temp2[0] = df_list_temp2[0].iloc[0:2,]

df_list_temp2[0] 
Out[158]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     2     5
```

The following result is what puzzles me:

```
df_list_temp1[0]
Out[159]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     2     5
```

I do not expect `df_list_temp1` to change!

Comment: `df_list_temp2 = df_list_temp1` - that's not a copy. Variable assignment doesn't copy objects.

Comment: `df_list_temp2 = df_list_temp1` doesn't copy temp1 into temp2, it just points temp2 to the same memory location as temp1, there is still only 1 object underneath.

Comment: You need to do a `Deep copy` that has its own copy of data and index. Use ```df_list_temp2 = df_list_temp1.copy()``` instead

Comment: @CavinDsouza - its not even a shallow copy. Its 2 references to a single python object. Use `id()` on each of them and you get the same value.

Comment: @tdelaney my bad, you're right, edited my reply.

Comment: @tdelaney @CavinDsouza Do you mean I should use ```df_list_temp2 = df_list_temp1.id()``` ??

Comment: @user2644687 Use `df_list_temp2 = df_list_temp1.copy()`

Comment: In Python, do we have this issue only in list or in any other data type?

Comment: @user2644687 the issue has nothing to do with *type*, the issue has to do with the semantics of *assignment*. `a = b` **never copies**, it says "the object being referenced by the name `b` is now being referenced by the name `a`". Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: How do I make the who dataframe "nan" but not affect the former? The command ``` df_list_temp2[0][:] = np.nan ``` does affect the previous even if I have ```.copy()``` in the assignment.